# Batch file - check output of exe

Tags: batch-file, command-line, executable

I haven't worked with batch files before but I would like to create a batch file that runs a command line program which will output one of two lines depending on success or failure. Is there any way I can capture the executable's output without writing it to a temporary file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the program in a `for /f` loop (example):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('myProgram.exe -a -b -c') do if /i "%%~a"=="failure" (call:dothis) else call:success
if %errorlevel%==0 call:success
if %errorlevel%==1 call:dothis
goto:eof

:dothis
echo Error found.
exit /b 1

:success
echo No error found.
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've adapted to code slightly to suit my needs but it was very helpful